# How do i extract text, tables and images from PDF using python

Tags: python, pdf, extract, text-extraction

I have a PDF file that consists of text, images and tables. How do I extract the 3 such that it identifies what to extract and does it on its own?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a package called PDFMiner.
Please go through its documentation for text extraction.

Here's where I would go reference:
http://denis.papathanasiou.org/archive/2010.08.04.post.pdf